# Erlang interpreter: Vi mode

Tags: erlang

I'm currently trying to get my hands dirty with Erlang. Also, in the (zsh) shell, I have got accustomed to using vi mode for line editing (`set -o vi`).

So: Is there a way to make the Erlang interpreter use more vi-like keybindings?

Comment: Readline can be configured to use vi key bindings, right? If so, you could use `rlwrap` around the Erlang shell.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes! Just call it as

```
rlwrap erl -oldshell
```

*NOTE:* you may need to install rlwrap (readline wrapper) and adjust your .inputrc (`set editing-mode vi`)

Comment: To get `rlwrap` to pass `C-g` down to `erl`, you'll want to add `"\C-g": rlwrap-direct-keypress` to your `~/.inputrc`, possibly inside an `$if` block [as the `rlwrap` manpage suggests](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/rlwrap/rlwrap.1.en.html#SPECIAL_KEYS_AND_BINDABLE_COMMANDS). You'll need `rlwrap` >= [0.43](https://github.com/hanslub42/rlwrap/blob/master/NEWS)

Answer (score 1):

No!

Well you could write your own line edit module and use that.